# I'm receiving a 'expected expression' error on my plurality code

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, cs50

As the title states, I'm working on a cs50 program which will simulate a simple plurality vote. Upon a glance, my code seems fine. However, when I try to compile it I am receiving an error:

```
plurality.c:71:9: error: expected expression
if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
^
```

As far as I am concerned, my code is correct. I have matched the brackets, I have made sure the if statement is correctly implemented. Could anyone tell me why I am receiving this error

Here is my code, maybe some wise individual can show what is wrong.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    (
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    )
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int winner;
    winner = candidates[0].votes;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > winner)
        {
            winner = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == winner)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I assume there is an issue outside of the if statement which has been flagged up by the compiler, which is why I have included the whole program. If someone could explain to me why I'm being stupid, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on the compiler error message you need to switch from `if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0;` to `if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)`, but you are already doing that in your code, recompile and see what happens.

Comment: Apologies, I typed in the error incorrectly. My actual code states the latter statement

Comment: It appears that `<cs50.h>` includes `<stdbool.h>`. FYI, `bool`, `true`, and `false` not defined in C; to use them you must `#include <stdbool.h>` (directly or through some other means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    (
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    )
    return false; `
```

You are using parenthesis instead of curly brackets in this for-loop block.

Comment: Dear lord, how embarrassing. Thanks mate!